# How do I set the value of a WordPress custom field from another custom field?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

The user is asked to provide a custom field value whilst filling in a form: an event_end_date to show in an event listing when an event has finished.

I want to be able to take that value and also apply it to another custom field to cause the theme to exclude it from being listed, which it does based on the value of an Expiry Date custom  field (event_expire_date).

Usefully, the form (WP User Frontend Pro) provides an Action Hook option that I have added to the form before the submit button. As I understand it, this calls a named function (I've called it 'set_expire_date').

I've added the following code to the theme's functions.php:

```
function set_expire_date () {
    $event_expire_date = $event_end_date;
}
```

After submission I expected that the event_end_date in the custom field would be populated but it is not.

To test, I have tried setting event_expire_date to an absolute value instead (based on the appropriate date / time format) but that is not populating the custom field event_end_date either.

Comment: Yeah this wont work, `$event_end_date` is not even declared so will probably throw an error or warning. I assume your form creates a post as an entry?

Comment: Yes the form creates a custom post type. I am new to this (as you'll have noticed) but I understood you didn't need to declare variables in PHP.

$event_end_date would have been set earlier in the form though as takes the user's input. I can see that $event_expire_date won't have been declared previously.